# What's wrong with this code in Android (PHP + MySQL)?

Tags: java, php, android, json, save

I have a problem with my application. I'm trying to make a register form in Android, but I have some problems.

When I'm running this app, everything is great, but when I try to save data, it shows me a error message `Unknown Status!`, I don't know what's wrong!

Could you, please, help me.

***Below is my code:***

PS: I tried [Stealz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18272921/662581) and now I receive the error `username exist`, but my table has just one insert.

---

**nota_spinner.xml**

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TableRow
  android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Register Form "
    android:layout_span="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</TableRow>

<View
android:layout_height="1dip"
android:background="#CCCCCC" />

  <TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Input Username :"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ems="10" >
  </EditText>

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Input Password/Confirm Password :"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <TableRow>
  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ems="6"
      android:inputType="textPassword" >
  </EditText>
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text=" Again " />

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/txtConPassword"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ems="7"
      android:inputType="textPassword" >
  </EditText>
  </TableRow>

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Input Name :"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/txtName"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ems="10" >
  </EditText>

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Input Email :"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
      android:ems="10" >
  </EditText>

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Input Tel :"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/txtTel"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:inputType="phone"
      android:ems="10" >
  </EditText>
 <Button
 android:id="@+id/btnSave"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Save" />


</TableLayout >
<View
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="#CCCCCC" />

<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="By.. ThaiCreate.Com" />

</LinearLayout>

</TableLayout>
```

**Class.java**

```
public class Class extends Activity {


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.nota_spinner);

    // Permission StrictMode
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    // btnSave
    final Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    // Perform action on click
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(SaveData())
            {
                // When Save Complete
            }
        }   
    });

}

public boolean SaveData()
{

    // txtUsername,txtPassword,txtName,txtEmail,txtTel
    final EditText txtUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUsername); 
    final EditText txtPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPassword); 
    final EditText txtConPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtConPassword); 
    final EditText txtName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtName); 
    final EditText txtEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEmail); 
    final EditText txtTel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtTel); 


        // Dialog
        final AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        ad.setTitle("Error! ");
        ad.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on); 
        ad.setPositiveButton("Close", null);

        // Check Username
        if(txtUsername.getText().length() == 0)
        {
            ad.setMessage("Please input [Username] ");
            ad.show();
            txtUsername.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        // Check Password
        if(txtPassword.getText().length() == 0 || txtConPassword.getText().length() == 0 )
        {
            ad.setMessage("Please input [Password/Confirm Password] ");
            ad.show();
            txtPassword.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        // Check Password and Confirm Password (Match)
             if(!txtPassword.getText().toString().equals(txtConPassword.getText().toString()))
        {
            ad.setMessage("Password and Confirm Password Not Match! ");
            ad.show();
            txtConPassword.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        // Check Name
        if(txtName.getText().length() == 0)
        {
            ad.setMessage("Please input [Name] ");
            ad.show();
            txtName.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        // Check Email
        if(txtEmail.getText().length() == 0)
        {
            ad.setMessage("Please input [Email] ");
            ad.show();
            txtEmail.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        // Check Tel
        if(txtTel.getText().length() == 0)
        {
            ad.setMessage("Please input [Tel] ");
            ad.show();
            txtTel.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }


        String url = "blahblah/saveADDData.php";

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sUsername",    txtUsername.getText().toString()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sPassword", txtPassword.getText().toString()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sName", txtName.getText().toString()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sEmail", txtEmail.getText().toString()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sTel", txtTel.getText().toString()));

        /** Get result from Server (Return the JSON Code)
         * StatusID = ? [0=Failed,1=Complete]
         * Error    = ? [On case error return custom error message]
         * 
         * Eg Save Failed = {"StatusID":"0","Error":"Email Exists!"}
         * Eg Save Complete = {"StatusID":"1","Error":""}
         */

         String resultServer  = getHttpPost(url,params);

        /*** Default Value ***/
        String strStatusID = "0";
        String strError = "Unknow Status!";

        JSONObject c;
        try {
            c = new JSONObject(resultServer);
            strStatusID = c.getString("StatusID");
            strError = c.getString("Error");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Prepare Save Data
        if(strStatusID.equals("0"))
        {
            ad.setMessage(strError);
            ad.show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(Nota.this, "Save Data Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            txtUsername.setText("");
            txtPassword.setText("");
            txtConPassword.setText("");
            txtName.setText("");
            txtEmail.setText("");
            txtTel.setText("");
        }


    return true;
}


public String getHttpPost(String url,List<NameValuePair> params) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) { // Status OK
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Log", "Failed to download result..");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str.toString();
}


}
```

**And this is my php file saveADDData.php**

```
<?
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("retailer");

/*** for Sample 
    $_POST["sUsername"] = "a";
    $_POST["sPassword"] = "b";
    $_POST["sName"] = "c";
    $_POST["sEmail"] = "d";
    $_POST["sTel"] = "e";
*/

$strUsername = $_POST["sUsername"];
$strPassword = $_POST["sPassword"];
$strName = $_POST["sName"];
$strEmail = $_POST["sEmail"];
$strTel = $_POST["sTel"];

/*** Check Username Exists ***/
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE Username = '".$strUsername."' ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
$objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
if($objResult)
{
    $arr['StatusID'] = "0"; 
    $arr['Error'] = "Username Exists!"; 
    echo json_encode($arr);
    exit();
}

/*** Check Email Exists ***/
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE Email = '".$strEmail."' ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
$objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
if($objResult)
{
    $arr['StatusID'] = "0"; 
    $arr['Error'] = "Email Exists!";    
    echo json_encode($arr);
    exit();
}

/*** Insert ***/
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO member (Username,Password,Name,Email,Tel) 
    VALUES (
        '".$strUsername."',
        '".$strPassword."',
        '".$strName."',
        '".$strEmail."',
        '".$strTel."'
        )
    ";

$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
if(!$objQuery)
{
    $arr['StatusID`enter code here`'] = "0"; 
    $arr['Error'] = "Cannot save data!";    
}
else
{
    $arr['StatusID'] = "1"; 
    $arr['Error'] = ""; 
}

/**
    $arr['StatusID'] // (0=Failed , 1=Complete)
    $arr['Error'] // Error Message
*/

mysql_close($objConnect);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: A terribly phrased question that just dumps blocks of code with minimal effort to describe any expected input and expected output, or lists any attempted efforts to find the cause.

Answer (score 0):

From what i see, you are getting error "Unknown Status" because you are getting response as StatusId = 0. And that you might get according to your php at multiple places(Username exist,Email exists).

What i suggest you give different statusId to different errors like username give id=11 for exists, email exists give 22, and check that on the android side as error, so you can give a specific message for error, than saying unknown error, because you know what error you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Now I receive the error "username exist", but my table has just one insert. I can't figure out what's wrong! Any suggestions ?